# Stripe Transfers: create transfer without having appropriate charge to use as a source_transaction

Tags: python, stripe-payments, payment-gateway

I have a piece of functionality which is made to transfer funds to a connected Stripe account. In our account payouts setting configured to “automatic” so I use source_transaction parameter to tie transfer with transaction to avoid potential problems with insufficient available balance. Now I need to transfer an amount of such value when I don’t have any “pending” transactions to cover that size of amount and any attempts to perform a transfer ending up with this “insufficient balance” exception.

**What I’ve tried:**

- to pass a source_transaction charge with “available” status (got “insufficient funds” error)
- wandering through Stripe documentation and Stackoverflow posts to figure out the potential solution (still can’t find one)

Would be great if someone could help me to answer to these **questions**:

- Retrieving balance using API gives me a negative amount in the “available” section. But as far as I understand it’s not important since I use an existing charge as source_transaction, right?
- Considering things I mentioned above is there any way for me to perform a transfer without setting payouts to “manual” configuration with accumulating funds in “available” balance?

Had an idea to split this transfer onto a number of smaller ones, but that doesn’t seem like a good one for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Retrieving balance using API gives me a negative amount in the
> “available” section. But as far as I understand it’s not important
> since I use an existing charge as source_transaction, right?

You can't transfer money you don't have or that is incoming — I'm a little confused because you say you "don’t have any “pending” transactions" but then you also mention using `source_transaction` to point to a charge that is not available yet which is contradictory.

My *guess* here is that the payment you're using as `source_transaction` was already paid out and thus those funds aren't available to be connected to a transfer. Ultimately you can't transfer $x unless you have a payment of at least $x that you received recently and hasn't been settled and paid out to your bank account already.

I tested on a Stripe account(creating a large negative available balance by issuing refunds, then creating a new charge and transferring it with source_transaction) and it does work as long as the charge is not already used for another transfer or was paid out already.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and sorry for confusion. By "don't have any pending transactions" I meant that I don't have any payments that aren't paid out at the moment with amount enough to cover my Transfer. So it seems like I don't have any payment to pass to source_transaction which isn't paid out. Other payments that I can use as a source_transaction is simply less than amount of the Transfer

Comment: So it seems like I have only two options here? To wait until I'll get payment for more than amount of the Transfer (so I can use it as a source_transaction until it will be paid out) or to switch account to manual payouts so I could use funds for transfer from accumulated in account

Comment: " I don't have any payments that aren't paid out at the moment with amount enough to cover my Transfer" then you can't do the transfer, since you're asking Stripe to 'float' you money to transfer to your connected account, you can't create money from nowhere!. Yes, you have to wait for an incoming payment or accumulate funds in your platform balance and monitor/manage them. Another common option here is you could also add cash directly to your Stripe account to fund your transfers : https://stripe.com/docs/connect/top-ups